# PHP Soap Basic Authorization without Header

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've got a project in front of me that requires me to build a Soap Client in PHP and pass with the call/request a basic authorization. The client's WSDL doesn't specify a header. This is throwing me off because the basic authorization is needed to access the API in order to use the webservice (a simple user lookup).

This is my code:

```
<?php
try {
$fullname = "Joe Smith";
$zipcode = "33149";
$session = "1a2b3c4d5e6f";
```

$client = new SoapClient('example.wsdl', array('location'=>'https://webservice/location', 'username'=>"Green", 'password'=>"tearocks"));

$search = $client->userSearch($session, $fullname, $zipcode);
print $search;
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>

The result displays "Unauthorized Request", a 401 error. I've gone through the php.net manual and various ebooks without avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Try passing "login" instead of "username" according to the [docs](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) that's what is used.

Comment: Thanks. I did pass login but my result is still 'unauthorized request'. Since this is ultimately passing XML, would trying SimpleXML work for a Soap web service?

Comment: @aethon try print $client->__getLastResponseHeaders; see what the real headers are. In your options you have to first enable 'trace' = true, before the above method will work.

Comment: that would return null since the wsdl doesn't specify headers for the request or response. I did try __getLastResponse though but that returne null too.

Comment: @aethon as I said in my last comment. In your options you have to first enable 'trace' = true, before the above method will work. According to the docs those functions don't return anything unless you enable it first.

Comment: This is the right answer, basic authorization is using HTTP authentication and actually has nothing to do with SOAP headers or the body of the request.